# Execute a script based on SQS message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I would like to know if i can execute a script based on a SQS message.

My requirement is to execute script in EC2 when i receive a queue message in SQS.

I am using AWS SDK to interact with SQS.

Thanks & Regards,
Srivignesh KN

Comment: Just write your program to parse SQS message and run process on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mark, thank you for the suggestions.

I was able to find a solution and implement this in the following manner using boto library.

```
import boto.sqs
#--------------Establishing Connection ------------------
conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(
    "myregion",
aws_access_key_id='myaccesskey',
aws_secret_access_key='mysecretaccesskey')
print conn.get_all_queues()
#----------------Processing the queue ------------------
my_queue=conn.get_queue('MySqsQueue')
print "My Queue is ",my_queue
rs=my_queue.get_messages()
length=len(rs)
print "Number of messages in the queue is",length
m=rs[0]
MsgBody=m.get_body()
print "Message Body is ",MsgBody
---My Script Execution/Processing---
#--------------Clearing the queue---------------
conn.purge_queue(my_queue)
```

Thanks & Regards,

Srivignesh KN

Answer (score 1):

An SQS message cannot automatically trigger a script to execute on your EC2 server. An SQS message does not automatically do anything. You have to create an application that will poll for SQS messages and then perform the necessary actions based on the messages it receives.

Comment: Thank you @mark, I am looking for examples to poll sqs queue using aws-sdk and do any action based on the sqs message. Appreciate your help.